# mpirun getting signal 9 after adding a method (added method makes the difference)

Tags: c++, cuda, mpi

I am still playing around with [Ramses GPU](http://www.maisondelasimulation.fr/projects/RAMSES-GPU/html/features.html)(which is written in C++ and CUDA) and everything works fine on a single GPU, so I wanted to start using MPI with ramses gpu. So I compiled the whole program with mpi and ran one of the test cases and everything went just fine. So I started to add another problem and recompiled it without any issues. After doing so I tried to run the code on two graphics cards but it always received a signal 9 (killed) on one of the ranks. So I tried to rerun the the example mentioned earlier but it ran into the same issue. After this I copied the code that had worked and recompiled it (yes, I touched all the files in order to let the code recompile everything). This thing was able to run the example and so I added just one method to the header and the class file, which I did not implement or call yet. After doing so and recompiling the rerun fails again. Putting the added code into comments and recompiling and rerunning leads to a working project, so I determined, it can't be an encoding error. How is it even possible, that an added function that does not even do anything makes the difference? (we are using qsub and cuda version 4.2 on our servers. I need to run all program with another program called gpurun)

Thanks in advance!

The code added to headerfile:

```
virtual void init_mhd_pbsedovblast();
```

The code added to class file:

```
 void HydroRunBaseMpi::init_mhd_pbsedovblast(){}
```

Comment: Well, and what is that method?

Comment: I did not think, it was important, as I did not do anything within the method and the compiler runs through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug into the code a little deeper and found out some interesting stuff. The code builds a CPU and GPU version by using CUDA. For some reason it jumped into an if clause that it should not have jumped into (I still can't tell why.) The execution of the code led to a nil pointer which happened to receive a call. This is why the process crashed with an out of memory exception. This problem was reproducable when I added the function and it stopped happening after putting the function in comments. What finally resolved the problem was using

```
make clean; make;
```

in order to put away all of those files already built and rebuild everything from skretch. I still don't know what the real issue was, but probably someone will need this information in the future.